# How to use Mergerfs to have multiple disks for /home

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive, unionfs

My growing number of users and their growing projects is pushing towards the limit. Disk usage is touching 100% already for /home.

I need to have a secondary HDD (/dev/sdb1), move some users to that device.
Then finally, I'm trying to use mergerfs to mount my old home partition (/dev/sda2) and the new (/dev/sdb1) to /home. So all users could be found normally under /home/

In `/etc/fstab` I commented out the line for the old /home and added:

> #MergerFS for Home

> /dev/sdb1:/dev/sda2 /home fuse.mergerfs allow_other,use_ino,category.create=mfs,fsname=home,nonempty 0 0

Then, I `mount -a`, but unfortunately /home is not accessible:

> ls: cannot access '/home': No such file or directory

Rebooting did not help either.

Comment: Is there a version of Ubuntu being used?

Comment: Thanks @David, it's 18.04.6 LTS .. the error in the dmesg while logging is related to timeout finding the device "/dev/sdb1:/dev/sda2" .. stopping the system from booting. Maybe because mergerfs is FUSE, not loaded early. I'm not sure what the solution could be.